# Select distinct rows from two datatables using LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have been tasked to create a generic class that takes two DataTable and returns the differences in another DataTable. The tables that are sent to my class are guaranteed to have the same structure (same number of columns, same column names, etc.) but the data will probably be different. The idea here is that I will receive the original table and the table as it has been updated. I already have a working solution but I wanted to try and see if there was a working solution with LINQ as I have very little experience with it.

The solution I have now does a comparison between the two tables and when it finds any rows that match, it removes them. By the end, the only rows that remain are the ones that the two tables do not share.

Does anyone have any idea if this is possible with LINQ and what that solution would look like?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Except`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb300779(v=vs.100).aspx), which compares two collections and returns the difference...

```
Dim tbl1 As DataTable = ds.Tables("tbl1")
Dim tbl2 As DataTable = ds.Tables("tbl2")
Dim diff = tbl1.AsEnumerable().Except(tbl2.AsEnumerable(), DataRowComparer.[Default])
```

You could wrap this in a method that takes two databales as input, returning *diff*.

```
Public Function GetDifference(tbl1 As DataTable, tbl2 As DataTable) As DataTable
    Return tbl1.AsEnumerable().Except(tbl2.AsEnumerable(), DataRowComparer.[Default])
End Function
```

I haven't tested this, but it should work for your scenario.

Comment: This is extremely close, however it seems as if ordering matters here. The case that tbl2 has more rows than tbl1 keeps giving me an empty enumeration. Thank you for the answer, it's got me headed in the right direction!

Comment: @HoustonMiller, no problem - if its helpful, you can upvote :)